# How to echo all the files in the folder using shell script? Folder path will be passed as argument

Tags: windows, shell

Echoing all the files in folder.

I tried to execute the following shell script in windows by passing folder path as an argument. But the path is echoed

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in $1\\*  # $1 refers to C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tempo\
do
  echo $filename
done;
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\tempo\*
```

Comment: if I'm understanding just: dir /b

Comment: I'd recommend using the linux path, not the windows path, and use forward slashes. Try `/c/Users/lenovo/Desktop/tempo/*`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't got @kenny can please mention it properly

Comment: @PaulHodges no I need to execute it in windows only,so I need to give Windows path only and I'm passing the path name as argument to shell script

Comment: @kenny thank you , I got it. We just need to do : dir //path

Comment: actually meant "dir /b \\path", but I wasn't sure what you were asking @NikhilJadhav

Comment: "in windows only" - you mean *from* windows? Sorry to hear it, lol ;)

Comment: Thank you @kenny